# jquery dealing with same form button over loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to allow jquery to accept the form data and send it to flask, which I completed already. However, 2 issues:

1. it only accept the first form, that is the same form (with same IDs are repeated for each element and I want them all to be able to submit).
2. when any submit happens it is as it appeared on the first element form.

**HTML:**

```
{{element[i]}}
{% if model == 'vsm' %}
    <form id="judgeForm">
        <button name="judge" id="accept" value="accept"> Relevant</button>
        <button name="judge" type="submit" id="reject" value="reject">Not Relevant</button>
    </form>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
{% endif %}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('form[id="judgeForm"]').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            data: {
               accept: $('#accept').val(),
               reject: $('#reject').val(),
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/judge'
         })
         .done(function(data) {
            $('#accept').hide();
            $('#reject').hide();
            $('#successAlert').text(data.msg).show();

         })
      // $('form[id="judgeForm"]').reset();
   });
});
```

Each element[i] has a form, however the jquery only accept the first and after it is submited all the other forms are locked, which I tried to fix by reseting the form at the end but I'm not too sure why it didn't work. Also when the jquery only accepts the first, that even for example element[5] is submited, the form for element[0] is the one that is activated.

I tried to use .each as well with the jquery, but it didn't work and that why I posted my closest work and maybe that there is another way around it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an unique id for each form. Using the same id for every form will make jquery/javascript to pick the first one.